# Implementing a Shapes application using the following criteria - small project

Tags: java, arraylist, drawable

Create a Shape interface which has an area() method which returns the area of the shape as a double. Create classes Circle and Rectangle which implement the Shape interface. These classes have attributes which reflect their dimensions (radius for a circle, height and width for a rectangle) which are set by their constructors.

Create a Drawable interface with setColour(Color c), setPosition(int x, int y), and draw(Graphics g) methods. Create the classes DrawableCircle and DrawableRectangle with appropriate constructors which extend Circle and Rectangle respectively and implement the Drawable interface.

Create a ShapesDriver class which extends Frame and has the main and  paint(Graphics g) methods in it. Within ShapesDriver create an ArrayList of type Drawable. Place into this array list a DrawableCircle and a DrawableRectangle where you have set the dimensions, position and colour. In the paint method iterate through the ArrayList and the invoke the draw method for each shape.

Here's where I've got to but I can't seem to get the drawable classes to work?

package shape;

```
public interface Shape
{
    public double area();
}
```

package shape;

```
public abstract class Circle implements Shape
{
    private double radius;

    Circle(double radius)
    {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double area()
    {
        return radius;
    }

}
```

package shape;

```
public abstract class Rectangle implements Shape
{
    public double height, width;

    Rectangle(double Height, double Width)
    {
        this.height = Height;
        this.width = Width;
    }

    public double area()
    {
        return width * height;
    }
}
```

package shape;

```
import java.awt.*;

public interface Drawable
{ 
    public void setColour(Color c);
    public void setPosition(double x, double y);
    public void draw(Graphics g);
}
```

package shape;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class DrawableCircle extends Circle implements Drawable
{
    public DrawableCircle(double radius)
    {
        super(radius);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColour(Color c)
    {
        c = Color.ORANGE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPosition(int x, int y)
    {
        x = 100;
        y = 150;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        //g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
    }

}
```

package shape;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class DrawableRectangle extends Rectangle implements Drawable
{
    private double x, y;

    public DrawableRectangle(double height, double width)
    {
        super(height, width);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColour(Color c)
    {
        this.setColour(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPosition(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

}
```

Comment: How to do the whole thing? or more specifically the drawable interface

Comment: Look at my answer. That should get you started. Work on that. If you have problems, come back ask for help. Show you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started

```
public interface Shape {
    public double area(); 
}

public class Circle implements Shape{
    // constructors
    // radius
    // implement area();
}

public class Rectangle implements Shape {
    // constructors
    // height, width
    // implement area();
}

public interface Drawable {
    public void setColor(Color c);
    public void setPoistion(int x, int y);
    public void draw(Graphics g);
}

public class DrawableCirlce extends Circle implements Drawable {
    // constructors
    // implement setColor();
    // implement setPosition();
    // implement draw();
}

public class DrawableRectangle extends Rectangle implements Drawable {
    // constructors
    // implement setColor();
    // implement setPosition();
    // implement draw();
}
```

Comment: I've implemented the code above, but I have an error on the draw section of the drawableRectangle class?

Comment: Does the error say you need to initialize your values? If yea, you should initialize x and y with 0 value. I would initialize all my class member variable with some dummy value.

Comment: Also in DrawableCircle, you should make x and y class members, like you did in DrawableRectangle. That way you can use x and y in other methods.

Comment: It says 'incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int'. for the rectangle and the circle one says it can't find the vairables?

Comment: You should declare x and y as int. positions are ints. They don't use double values

Comment: Also in your Circle, area() doesn't = radius. area = r * r * pi.

Comment: In your drawable classes you should declare Color c as a class member, as well as x and y.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My drawableCircle class can't find the height and width need for the draw method. Makes sense as unlike rectangle it uses the radius. I've used (radius * 2) for both which kinda makes sense! Just need to make a shapesDriver class now. Thanks again!

Comment: Circles dont have heights and widths. read your own instructions... (radius * radius * Math.PI).